# How to write generic function which the implementation access the property of type

Tags: swift

I am trying to write a generic function in the the body of the function, it reads one of the property of the Type.

My function:

```
func doSomething<Key>(
        _ key: Key
    ) -> Int  {
    let a = key.aProperty
    return doSomethingElse(a)
}
```

and I have put different struct to doSomething as long as they have the 'aProperty' as one of its properties

```
struct A {
   let a : String
   let aProperty: String
}
 struct B {
   let b : String
   let aProperty: String
}

let a = A()
let b = B()
doSomething<A>(a)
doSomething<B>(b)
```

But I get compiler error in my doSomething function saying 'Value of type 'Key' has no member 'aProperty' .

So can you please tell me what am I missing in defining my doSomething function?

Comment: I could be wrong, but you might be confusing the usage of Generics with Protocols. Swift will let you conform a Generic to a Protocol which will get the effect you're looking for.

Comment: The docs are pretty good: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use protocol.

```swift
func doSomethingElse(_ a: String) -> Int { 0 }

protocol HasAProperty {
    var aProperty: String { get }
}
func doSomething<Key: HasAProperty>(
    _ key: Key
) -> Int  {
    let a = key.aProperty
    return doSomethingElse(a)
}

struct A: HasAProperty {
    let a : String
    let aProperty: String
}
struct B: HasAProperty {
    let b : String
    let aProperty: String
}

let a = A(a: "a", aProperty: "aProperty")
let b = B(b: "b", aProperty: "aProperty")
doSomething(a)
doSomething(b)
```